# Can't Bring Network Up & Running After Pi-hole Configuration

Tags: networking, centos7

On my VPS(CentOS 7), I was trying configure OpenVPN + PiHole. During the process I had to restart the networking. Afterwards the networking got broken and locked me out. Now I can only access my Droplet from the console in the Digital Ocean control panel.

Once I'm in, I can see that everything works as expected(Apache, SSH, Gitlab, etc.) but since my networking is down, nothing can be accessed from the outside.

I tracked down the root cause of the problem to broken `eth0` settings. I don't believe it's a firewall issue. My IP and Netmask settings were broken. They were falsely changed by Pi-Hole. I tried fixing them but I still get the same error message I got before trying to fix my settings when I execute `systemctl status network`:

[image]

How should I proceed?

### Update 1

`ifcfg-eth0`:

```
DEVICE=eth0
BOOTPROTO=none
ONBOOT=yes
IPADDR=104.248.31.98
PREFIX=24
GATEWAY=104.248.16.1
DNS1=208.67.222.222
DNS2=208.67.222.220
USERCTL=no
```

`route -n`:

[image]

### Update 2

`route -n` after reboot:

[image]

`ip a sh`:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gateway is non-local, ie, it's on a different subnet to your ethernet interface.  The whole point of a default gateway is that it should be a locally-accessible host that can route traffic to and from the rest of the world.  Attempting to use a non-local gateway produces the `network is unreachable` error you're seeing, and without a gateway your traffic can't get to the internet.

(There are exceptions to this, but they're unusual, to do with point-to-point routes, and it's not normal to use a wide (eg `/24`) netmask with such.)

Check **all three** settings - your IP, your netmask, your default gateway - with DO, and correct the one (or ones) that are wrong.

Comment: I should just be editing the file `ifcfg-eth0` under `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts`, right? Also what do you mean by DI?

Comment: Yes.  And I meant the provider of your VPS, who I'd assumed was Digital Island based on the IP address.  Sorry about the confusion if it's not.

Comment: FYI, it's Digital Ocean.

Comment: Each field(IP, netmask, default gateway) on my `ifcfg-eth0` file is as it's seen on my DO panel, under my `Public Network` settings. But it doesn't currently work. When you say check, do you mean I need some other data?

Comment: @CanSürmeli If you've set up ifcfg-eth0 as shown in your question right now, then restart the VPS. The routes shown don't correspond to that configuration.

Comment: @MichaelHampton I did a restart before and just now. It didn't help.

Comment: @CanSürmeli can you update the question with the new routing table?  Michael has a point about the mismatch, which makes us think something's not as advertised.  And the output of `ip a sh` might be useful, too.

Comment: @MadHatter updated

Comment: OK, everything is now consistent with what I'd expect, except that default gateway, which *does not make any sense*.  You should query this with DO.

Comment: The issue is handled. Finally, DO contacted me back and gave me the proper configuration for my `eth0`. Thanks a lot for your help.